# Selenium Keep Checking till text is found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to find a specific text and I can only do it using the `className` under the `span` tag. Unfortunately, the `className` is common for various other `span` tags. If I try finding the `text` using `className`, there is a high chance that only the first occurrence of the `span tag ---> className` will be registered.

Is there any way I can keep checking the entire page till the last line for the `className--->text`?

I cannot use the `findElements()` method. Doing that will involve a lot of changes in the code, and since this is only a one-time affair, I don't want to go through all the hassle.

Comment: please share the relevant block of HTML code the element you want to find. we can find an element from `its parent or child or sibling also` using `Xpath` or `cssSelectors`.

Comment: Share your `HTML`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xpath: How do we select just the very last text node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098593/xpath-how-do-we-select-just-the-very-last-text-node)

Answer (score 1):

I use following methods to find element using text. if this doesn't work for you, you can create the similar methods by referring the post Madhan has suggested.

```
public WebElement findElementByText(String text){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]"));
}

public WebElement findElementByText(String text, boolean exactMatch){
    if (exactMatch){
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + text + "']"));
    }else{
        return findElementByText(text);
    }
}
```